# Numpy bitwise operator priority?

Tags: python, numpy, operators, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

What's the priority ranking of numpy bitwise operators & and | ?

if I do

```
a & b | c
```

what expression does it evaluate? `a & (b | c)` ? `(a & b) | c` ?

How about

```
a | b & c
```

I also assume NOT (~) has the highest priority?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a technique that you can use when your internet connection is down. It is applicable to many questions that you might have. The colloquial description of the technique is "Suck it and see".

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(2), repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
>>> all((a & b | c) == ((a & b) | c) for a, b, c in product(range(2), repeat=3))
True
>>> all((a & b | c) == (a & (b | c)) for a, b, c in product(range(2), repeat=3))
False
```

Comment: I definitely like the try and see approach.  One minor nitpick is that if the first statement is true the two operators could still have the same precedence, so it would be good to also check with the operators reversed `(a | b & c) == ((a | b) & c)`.  Since that is false you know that `&` has higher precedence than `|`, but it would be true for operators like `+` and `-` that are the same precedence.

Comment: Nice trick! @AndrewClark As you said, the first output alone does not imply that & precedes over |.  I think we have to use the outputs of both the statements to deduce that & precedes over |.   Otherwise, your method of switching the operators will be useful.

Answer (score 8):

Refer to [this section of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), and also [this page](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) (thanks @F.J.).

Priority is:

1. not (`~`)
2. and (`&`)
3. xor (`^`)
4. or (`|`)

This means that:

```
a & b | c == (a & b) | c
a | b & c == a | (b & c)
```

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary), `^` has higher precedence than `|`.  Easy to prove, `1 | 2 ^ 3 != (1 | 2) ^ 3`.